# How to extract information between xml tag

Tags: php, html, xml, xml-parsing

I am trying to convert an xml code of the form

```
  <document>
  <section>
    Some Text 1
    <theorem>
        Let $H$ be a real or complex Hilbert space.
    </theorem>
    Some Text 2
 </section>
 </document>
```

to html code

```
<div class="section">
    <div class="text">
      Some Text 1
    </div>
    <div class="theorem">
        Let $H$ be a real or complex Hilbert space.
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      Some Text 2
    </div>
  </div>
```

This is what done so far

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file("text.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
foreach($xml->children() as $tags){ 

    echo'<div class="section">';
        echo '<div class="theorem">'.$tags->theorem.'</div>'; 
    echo'</div>';

}
```

The problem is I am not sure how to extract `Some Text 1` and `Some Text 2` separately so I can echo each in `<div class="text"></div>` tag. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: What is `$tags`? How are you parsing the xml?

Comment: @PeeHaa, I have updated my post.